# Type hinting for class defined in a function

Tags: python, type-hinting

We are adding type hints to our code base and there's one specific case where I don't know how to do proper type hinting. We have a function that will create an instance of a specific class if it didn't yet exist. The class of which it creates an object is defined in the function itself to make it a Singleton. An example of such a function is given in the following piece of code:

```py
__GREETER = None

def get_greeter():
   global __GREETER

   class Greeter:
       def greet_user(name: str):
           print(f'Hello {name}')

   if not __GREETER:
       __GREETER = Greeter()

   return __GREETER
```

I was now wondering how we can add a type hint for the return type of the get_greeter() function. Can I just use `get_greeter() -> 'Greeter'` or should I do something different?

**Note** that there are indeed cleaner ways to define singletons since python 3 but refactoring that is something on the backlog.

Comment: If you move the `Greeter` class out of the `get_greeter` function the solution becomes trivial. "Can I just use ..." - no (have you tried it?).

Comment: That's correct but then everyone can just create a Greeter using `g = Greeter()` which removes the purpose of this piece of code, right?

I did indeed try it out first and didn't get any hints when calling the function but I wanted to be sure that it wasn't an issue with the IDE

Comment: In any case, given your current code, I don't know of any way of annotating the return type of `get_greeter`, as the return type isn't known outside the function.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to lock the class away. Python works out of convention and collaboration, it's not Java

Comment: I don't see any particular reason to put the class in the function. It gets redefined (unnecessarily) every time you call `get_greeter`. Just put the class definition outside the function.

Comment: @soetaertie Anyone can create an instance of `Greeter` once `get_greeter` has been called: `f = get_greeter(); g = type(f)()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a slight refactoring of your code, to make it a more generic approach. You can make a singleton pattern applicable, even if you expose your class. For eg. see below.

```
class Greeter:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(Greeter, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

    def greet_user(name: str):
        print(f'Hello {name}')
```

You can re-write your Greeter class, which makes sure its a singleton. Now for backward compatibility, keep the method you have as it is.

```
def get_greeter() -> Greeter:
    return Greeter()
```

It creates only one instance ever. And your hinting is also achieved.